# My ASUS pc seems to lose its bluetooth firmware when I dual boot? I have reset it numerous times.... frustrating

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, 15.04, bluetooth, asus

I have reset it numerous times.... frustrating.

```
wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/xbmm9vfg2fby2zn/fw-04ca_2006.hcd
sudo cp fw-04ca_2006.hcd /lib/firmware/brcm/BCM43142A0-04ca-2006.hcd
sudo modprobe -r btusb
sudo modprobe btusb
```

This is what I do every time to get the bluetooth working again.

```
[    0.184551] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    1.501933] psmouse serio4: elantech: assuming hardware version 4 (with firmware version 0x381f00)
[    9.977602] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.20
[    9.977615] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    9.977618] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    9.977620] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    9.977626] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   10.243919] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM43142A0-04ca-2006.hcd failed with error -2
[   10.243925] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: patch brcm/BCM43142A0-04ca-2006.hcd not found
[   12.252479] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x1003 tx timeout
[   20.540677] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   20.540679] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   20.540683] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   20.715433] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   20.715441] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   20.715447] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   23.061182] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x1003 tx timeout
```

Comment: Please edit to include `dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm' as this is very strange

Comment: Is the firmware still in the home directory after reboot before running any commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the only time I have heard of this happening with Ubuntu installed to a hard drive but we can change the attributes on `/lib/firmware/brcm` after putting the firmware in to see if it prevents the file from being deleted

```
wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/xbmm9vfg2fby2zn/fw-04ca_2006.hcd
sudo cp fw-04ca_2006.hcd /lib/firmware/brcm/BCM43142A0-04ca-2006.hcd
sudo chattr +i /lib/firmware/brcm/
```

Reboot and see if the problem still exists

Comment: This worked fantastically.

Answer (score 0):

Remember to 
`sudo chattr -i /lib/firmware/brcm`
before you do a distibution upgrade!

Any update to linux-firmware while the .../brcm folder is set to immutable will causethe update to fail. This will in turn cause the upgrade to crash.

I'm speaking from a rather unfortunate experience here.