# bluetooth headset problem (Ausdom m04 with bluetooth 4.0)

Tags: 14.04, sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, headset

I have a bluetooth headset (Ausdom m04). At first, I couldn't set up the device as the laptop couldn't find the device. Then, after a couple of hours, I managed to connect it but there was no sound. These two threads helped a lot by the way:

1. [My ASUS pc seems to lose its bluetooth firmware when I dual boot? I have reset it numerous times.... frustrating](https://askubuntu.com/questions/682426/my-asus-pc-seems-to-lose-its-bluetooth-firmware-when-i-dual-boot-i-have-reset-i/706844)
2. [Bluetooth device paired and connected (no sound)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/372071/bluetooth-device-paired-and-connected-no-sound)

Now, I have a problem which is about the quality of the sound. When playing sound through the headset, sound mode is Telephone Duplex. Even if I change it to High Fidelity Playback (A2DP), it still goes back to Telephone Duplex mode automatically.
Notes:
 - Ubuntu 14.04
 - Bluetooth headset supports A2DP.
 - Tested it on Win 7,8,8.1,10 and works like a charm.

Please help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to /etc/bluetooth/audio.conf:

[General]
Disable=Headset

then run
`sudo service bluetooth restart`

(taken from this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/319871/bluetooth-speaker-preferred-mode-high-fidelity-playback-a2dp-is-not-getting))